# viewWillAppear and later lifecycle events not called when UIViewController is set as root of UIWindow during launch

Tags: ios, swift

I have the following piece of code in my `application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)` method

```
self.window = self.window ?? UIWindow()
self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
let mainViewController = HomeViewController.instantiate() //here I just call the viewController through storyboard, set some properties and return its instance
window?.rootViewController = mainViewController
```

I checked and the only lifecycle events that are called when the `viewController` is added to the `window` are:

```
viewDidLoad
viewWillLayoutSubviews
viewDidLayoutSubviews
```

Anything after that is not called (this happens only when it is initially  added in the `window`, after that the events are called as they are supposed to). Safe Layout Guide is also not set (and I believe the same goes with other view properties). In order to bypass this issue I do the following:

```
window?.rootViewController = UIViewController()
```

and then

```
window?.rootViewController = mainViewController
```

It seems that this somehow forces the window to work correctly the second time it has its root view controller set.

However it seems that either there is something I am missing or there is some kind of lifecycle issue.

*Has anyone faced the same issue and found the underlying cause?*

Comment: Have you tried making self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible() after setting the window's rootViewConttroller?

Comment: What your `.instantiate()` method do?

Comment: @Shubham that was the issue. You can add it as an answer so that it shows better

Comment: @TheoK Sure, I'll

Comment: please show your didFinishaunch method code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try making the window key and Visible at the end after setting the root view controller of window.

```
self.window = self.window ?? UIWindow()
let mainViewController = HomeViewController.instantiate()
window?.rootViewController = mainViewController
self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```